# EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-publish

I am trying to publish an npm package but I keep getting this error.

Any idea how I can fix it. please help me.

thanks in advance.

error

```
EBUSY
 all lstat
 C:\hiberfil.sys
 -4082
  EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issues, try this:

1. Remove `node_modules` directory, `package-lock.json` file.
2. Run `npm install`
3. Run `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: Why though? Why should `c:\hiberfil.sys` come into play at all?

Answer (score 1):

I tried deleting node modules but it didn't work. The issue in my case was because of a wrongly imported dependency by VSCode, I fixed the issue by removing the last imports I added to my code.

Answer (score 0):

in my project, the reason is I imported the wrong module like this "import {umd} from 'vue'" ,check out your